# SQL Server foreign key filtered constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to have soft-delete in SQL Server database, I have the following simple relationship:

Blog table:

```
PK BlogId, Name, Deleted
```

Post table:

```
PK PostId, FK BlogId, Title, Deleted
```

Post table has a foreign key with a constraint which ensures that for each post there is an existing blog and when you delete blog you should delete all related posts.

But, **how to build constraint of FK taking into account soft-delete**, so when I set blog record as deleted it will force me to mark all related posts as deleted as well.

*Update: I found temporal tables very useful feature that could replace soft-delete because it tracks the whole history of changes including records deletion.* (but still interested in some way to have soft-delete in question)

Comment: You can't use FK constraints for that. You would have to handle this either in your delete logic (hopefully a stored procedure) or create triggers to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a composite foreign key on the `BlogId` and `Deleted` fields, and set the `ON UPDATE` option to `CASCADE`.

```
CREATE TABLE Blog (
    BlogId INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Deleted BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Blog PRIMARY KEY (BlogId),
    CONSTRAINT AK_Blog UNIQUE (BlogId, Deleted)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE Post (
    PostId INT NOT NULL,
    BlogId INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Deleted BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PostBlog FOREIGN KEY (BlogId, Deleted)
        REFERENCES Blog (BlogId, Deleted)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
GO

INSERT INTO Blog VALUES (1, 'Blog 1', 0);
INSERT INTO Post VALUES (1, 1, 'Post 1', 0);

UPDATE Blog SET Deleted = 1 WHERE BlogId = 1;

-- Notice that the `Deleted` field in `Post` is now '1' and not '0'.
SELECT * FROM Post;
```

Comment: But now im unable to delete a Post: `UPDATE Post SET Deleted = 1 WHERE PostId = 1;`

Comment: One approach would be to create dummy blog flagged as deleted, e.g. `INSERT INTO Blog VALUES (-1, 'Dummy', 1)`. Then whenever you want to delete a post, simply re-link the post to the dummy blog, e.g. `UPDATE Post SET BlogId = -1, Deleted = 1 WHERE PostId = 1`. Depending on your requirements, you may want to add an additional column to record the id of the blog to which the post originally related.